# Starscream use without http

Tags: swift, http, websocket

I am trying to establish a connection to a program on my computer. I found Starscream. It works wonderfully, but the primary use is to establish a port connection to transfer TCP Ascii data, as the software receiving the data is not http, Starscream disconnects. I have tried editing the helper classes etc, but this will a tad out of my depth.

I have made this part on android, where I simply define:
- IP address
- Port
- String that will produce exact tcp data value

Is there any way I can use Starscream in this manner and drop the http packets, or even "break" the code to do so?

if it helps see below how I am establishing connection using Starscream:

```
let ipAddress = ipAddressTF.text!

let port = portTF.text!

let oldData = lastDataSentTV.text!
lastDataSentTV.text = "attempting to connect to: " + ipAddress + ":" + port + "\r" + oldData

    var connectTo = "ws://" + ipAddress + ":" + port + "/"

    socket = WebSocket(url: NSURL(string: connectTo)!)
    socket.delegate = self
    socket.connect()
```

Comment: The problem is likely that the websocket is not secure (no SSL certificate) I have the same problem